# Find columns with differing values in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and and I want to find columns that contain differing values within rows, e.g.

```
import pandas, math
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, math.nan, 2], [math.nan, math.nan, 2]], 
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

My target is, obviously, column *A*. I did manage to select it by a rather ugly method

```
[k for k, v in df.to_dict('list').items() 
 if len(set(map(str, v))) > 1]
```

And I am not happy about it. Could anyone please suggest proper way for such an operation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `nunique`

```
df.fillna('NAN').nunique()==len(df)
Out[148]: 
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```